# HaxeFlixel - Error: invalid operation (%), probably mistake with loadGraphic

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I searched the HaxeFlixel forums, google, here and managed to fixed some other problems while trying to debug this myself, but no luck with the problem itself.

As best I can tell it seems like I did something silly when using `loadGraphic()` maybe? I keep wondering if I made a typo and the png for the sprite isn't there and that's why it's `null`, but I've checked it enough times to think that probably isn't it.

This is my error in neko when I move to `PlayState`...

```
haxelib run lime run "Project.xml" neko -debug
Running process: C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\haxelib.exe run lime run "Project.xml" neko -debug
Invalid operation (%)
Called from flixel.animation.FlxAnimationController::set_frameIndex line 638
Called from flixel.FlxSprite::updateFrameData line 1197
Called from flixel.FlxSprite::loadGraphic line 347
Called from Josh::new line 26
Called from Josh::$init line 13
Called from PlayState::addJosh line 54
Called from PlayState::create line 37
Called from flixel.FlxGame::switchState line 583
Called from flixel.FlxGame::update line 668
Called from flixel.FlxGame::step line 648
Called from flixel.FlxGame::onEnterFrame line 493
Called from openfl._legacy.events.EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent line 98
Called from openfl._legacy.display.DisplayObject::__dispatchEvent line 182
Called from openfl._legacy.display.DisplayObject::__broadcast line 161
Called from openfl._legacy.display.DisplayObjectContainer::__broadcast line 286
Called from openfl._legacy.display.Stage::__render line 1103
Called from openfl._legacy.display.Stage::__checkRender line 351
Called from openfl._legacy.display.Stage::__pollTimers line 1084
Called from openfl._legacy.display.Stage::__doProcessStageEvent line 430
Done(1)
```

This is my error with flash when switching to `PlayState`...

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter sourceBitmapData must be non-null.
    at flash.display::BitmapData/copyPixels()
    at flixel::FlxSprite/draw()[C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\flixel\3,3,11\flixel\FlxSprite.hx:777]
    at flixel.group::FlxTypedGroup/draw()[C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\flixel\3,3,11\flixel\group\FlxTypedGroup.hx:108]
    at flixel::FlxState/draw()[C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\flixel\3,3,11\flixel\FlxState.hx:58]
    at flixel::FlxGame/draw()[C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\flixel\3,3,11\flixel\FlxGame.hx:805]
    at flixel::FlxGame/onEnterFrame()[C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\flixel\3,3,11\flixel\FlxGame.hx:506]
```

`PlayState.hx`

```
package;

import flixel.FlxCamera;
import flixel.FlxG;
import flixel.FlxSprite;
import flixel.FlxState;
import flixel.FlxObject;
import flixel.util.FlxPoint;
import flixel.text.FlxText;
import flixel.tile.FlxTilemap;
import flixel.ui.FlxButton;
import flixel.util.FlxMath;
import flixel.util.FlxTimer;
import openfl.Assets;

/**
 * A FlxState which can be used for the actual gameplay.
 */
class PlayState extends FlxState
{
    private var level:FlxTilemap;
    private var camera:FlxCamera;
    public var josh:Josh;


    /**
     * Function that is called up when to state is created to set it up. 
     */
    override public function create():Void
    {
        super.create();

        addLevel();
        addJosh(12, 125);

        camera = FlxG.camera;
        FlxG.camera.follow(josh, FlxCamera.STYLE_LOCKON);
        add(camera);
    }

    function addLevel():Void
    {
        level = new FlxTilemap();
        level.loadMap(Assets.getText("assets/data/map.csv"), "assets/images/tileset.png", 32, 32);
        level.setTileProperties(1, FlxObject.NONE);
        add(level);
    }

    function addJosh(X:Int, Y:Int):Void
    {
        josh = new Josh(X, Y);
        add(josh);
    }

    /**
     * Function that is called when this state is destroyed - you might want to 
     * consider setting all objects this state uses to null to help garbage collection.
     */
    override public function destroy():Void
    {
        super.destroy();
    }

    /**
     * Function that is called once every frame.
     */
    override public function update():Void
    {
        super.update();

        FlxG.collide(level, josh);
    }

}
```

`Josh.hx`

```
package;

import flixel.FlxSprite;
import flixel.FlxG;
import flixel.FlxObject;
import flixel.util.FlxMath;
import flixel.util.FlxTimer;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Jacob
 */
class Josh extends FlxSprite
{

    var maxSpeed:Int = 120;
    var gravity:Int = 100;
    var maxFallSpeed:Int = 300;
    var jumpForce:Int = 140;
    var maxAcceleration:Int = 300;
    var _drag:Float = 1000;

    public function new(X:Float, Y:Float) 
    {
        super(X * 32, Y * 32 - 32);
        loadGraphic("assets/images/Mugger Space Cadet.png", true, 32, 64);
        setSize(25, 59);
        offset.set(4, 5);

        maxVelocity.y = maxFallSpeed;
        acceleration.y = gravity;
        drag.x = _drag;
    }

    override public function update():Void
    {
        if (alive) controls();

        super.update();
    }

    function controls():Void
    {
        var xForce:Float = 0;
        var jumping:Bool = false;

        if (FlxG.keys.anyPressed(["LEFT", "A"])) xForce--;
        if (FlxG.keys.anyPressed(["RIGHT", "D"])) xForce++;
        if (FlxG.keys.anyJustPressed(["SPACE", "UP", "W"])) jumping = true;
        if (FlxG.keys.anyJustReleased(["SPACE", "UP", "W"])) velocity.y = velocity.y * 0.5;

        xForce = FlxMath.bound(xForce, -1, 1);
        acceleration.x = xForce * maxAcceleration;
        if (jumping && isTouching(FlxObject.FLOOR)) {
            var finalJumpForce:Float = -(jumpForce + Math.abs(velocity.x * 0.25));
            velocity.y = finalJumpForce;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with Flixel, but it seems to me an issue with properly loading the asset. Have you checked that it can be found by the openfl asset system and that it actually contains an image?

Comment: I've used the asset before successfully and I can discern no difference in the arrangement. Same name, directory structure...Anything else I should check?

Comment: Can't think of anything else.  At this point I would attach a debugger and/or add some traces to the Flixel code.

Comment: Try `loadGraphic` with the `animated` parameter false in order to determine exactly what is wrong. If that works, your spritesheet might not be set up properly or something.

It's hard to help here because no one who works on flixel uses a version anywhere near here.